# Kafka parcel not installed well

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am using a `cloudera cluster (5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1)` and I installed the `Kafka parcel (2.0.1-1.2.0.1.p0.5)`. When I tried to add the kafka service on the cluster, I had the following error on every host I tried to add a role on : `Error found before invoking supervisord: User [kafka] does not exist.`
I created the user manually on every node needed, restarted the service, and it seemed to work until I tried to modify the kafka config with the cloudera manager. The cloudera's kafka configuration isn't "binded" to the real kafka configuration.

The error when I try to modify the `broker.id` :

> Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown
>   kafka.common.InconsistentBrokerIdException: Configured broker.id 101
>   doesn't match stored broker.id 145 in meta.properties. If you moved
>   your data, make sure your configured broker.id matches. If you intend
>   to create a new broker, you should remove all data in your data
>   directories (log.dirs).`